# How to set 'src' path for a JS file in theme folder using local Wordpress environment

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Trying to link a JS file to my header to make it dynamic. The CSS file works fine as I've linked it into functions.php and from there it uses @import to select modules of CSS in the folder. Preferably this would be the best way to link a JS file but can you link multiple and if so how?

Currently I'm using script tags with a url "js/header.js", this returns an error value in dev tools of

```
GET http://pd-g.local/.js/header.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I get WP to find the JavaScript file?

PD & G

┣ css

┃ ┗ header.css

┣ images

┃ ┗ fireplace.jpg

┣ js

┃ ┗ header.js

┣ footer.php

┣ front-page.php

┣ functions.php

┣ header.php

┣ index.php

┣ page.php

┣ post.php

┣ screenshot.png

┗ style.css

Answer (score 0):

In your function.php file:

```
<?php
//Add theme required js
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
function theme_scripts() {
if( !is_admin() ) {
//Theme script
wp_enqueue_script(
'script_js',
get_template_directory_uri() . '/script.js',
array(), //Add script name to load after if needed
null,
true );
}; }; ?>
```

Hope this is what you're looking for

Comment: Does this mean I should be using a file named **script.js**?